# frequent rejection of password Ubuntu 16.04 --no pattern

Tags: password

Several days ago my password started to be rejected frequently. I had to
type my password 2 or 3 times for sudo commands and sometimes open a new 
terminal before the password was accepted.

Authentication password requests frequently gave an invalid password message 1 or more times and frequently never succeeded. I needed to restart or turn my computer on and off 3 or 4 times before the password was accepted at the login screen.

In order to get into evolution mail I needed to completely remove seahorse and reenter the passwords. I had changed my password but still encountered this problem. I noticed that the log at boot included a message `systemd-ask-password.plymouth.path/start deleted...`.

There seems to be no pattern to this password bug. Sometimes my password works on the first try and sometimes it never succeeds. Several days before
this problem started there was an update for nvidia-340. Any advice 
about this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very weird; perhaps your keyboard has a physical issue.  Sometimes there's dirt/crumbs under the plastic and certain keys don't send an event unless you press them harder.  `sudo` switches to `noecho` mode when you enter the password so you can't see when a key fails to fire.  I would go over each char used in the password many times, just typing it lightly, and see if it occasionally misses being registered.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just had this start happening a few days ago, notably on the login, where it shows a dot for each character of the password typed. This shows that it is NOT a key not working - it's just randomly failing to accept the absolutely correct password, frequently.

Comment: I removed commas from my password and that seems to have solved the problem.